# Best practice for monolithic Rails app that provides multiple consumers for RabbitMQ round-robin queue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, amqp

I need multiple consumers in my Rails app to process messages from RabbitMQ that are delivered using the round-robin pattern.

[image: Round-Robin]

All the consumers (C1, C2) have the same exact logic. How do people achieve this without booting up a new app instance for each consumer/worker? Is there a pattern that would allow C1 and C2 to exist in the same app instance?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/ruby-amqp/hutch. Same for your other question.

Comment: I've the same question, and I appreciate if you can share your learnings as an answer